# upgrading from asp.net mvc 2.0 to 3.0 issues

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

after upgrade, all the pages see Models as Object.

I've upgraded using migration guide [**here**](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#0.1__Toc274034210)

basically just copying some scripts, and re-mapping mvc assembly reference to 3.0

For some reason, all of my controls are now not seeing any properties on my models.

here is how i define the model type:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<WebMVC.Models.WeatherModel>" %>
```

usage:

```
<%: Html.TextBox("DateFromText", Model.DateFrom.ToShortDateString())%>
```

i now get compile errors that "object" does not contain definition for AnyProperty.

UPDATE

thanks to SLax i fixed the object issue. Now getting the following error:

**The type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.ComplexObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.**

ok.. fixed this by adding assembly reference in web.config:

```
<add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have references to System.Web.Mvc.dll version 2 in one of the *two* Web.config files.

Comment: i will.. still have another issue to figure out

Answer (score 2):

You will want to enter the following into the web.config file:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
```